# Keras 2D CNN input and output shape for geospatial data/ ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, geospatial

I'm trying to build a 2D CNN based on geospatial data to be able to capture spatial patterns. I want to fit a model and use it to predict a timestep in the future for the Australian domain, i.e. I would like the model to predict a geospatial map of Australia based on physical variables. Currently, I have 7 predictor variables (percentile ranks, so value ranges between 0 and 1) and one binary target variable. Each predictor and the target variable have 137 latitudes and 181 longitudes, which I interpreted as image height and width, and for the training period have 215 timesteps (and 1 timestep for the test period) so that

```
X_train.shape = (215,137,181,7)
X_test.shape = (1,137,181,7)
X_fut.shape = (1,137,181,7)
y_train.shape = (215,137,181)
y_test.shape = (1,137,181)
y_fut.shape = (1,137,181)
```

I.e. for each timestep, I have seven grids (or images if you will) as predictor variables, and 1 target variable. I tried to run a 2D CNN based on 1 predictor variable, i.e.

```
X_train.shape = (215,137,181,1)
X_test.shape = (1,137,181,1)
X_fut.shape = (1,137,181,1)
y_train.shape = (215,137,181)
y_test.shape = (1,137,181)
y_fut.shape = (1,137,181)
```

and wrote a test code for the model

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=-100, input_shape=(137, 181, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='sigmoid',padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=1, activation='sigmoid', padding='same'))
```

I set all gridcells with nan (here ocean) to -100 and masked them with the masking layer to be able ignore gridcells that are always nan. Now this all works, and I can compile and fit the model

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['binary_accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
pred_fut = model.predict(X_fut)
```

and I the image I get looks the way I want it look (a bit blurry perhaps)

```py
plt.imshow(pred_fut.reshape(137,181))
plt.show()
```

[image]

So then I tried to read in all my predictors, i.e. the full 7, so that

```
X_train.shape = (215,137,181,7)
X_test.shape = (1,137,181,7)
y_train.shape = (215,137,181)
y_test.shape = (1,137,181)
```

and my model is defined with a new input shape as

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=-100, input_shape=(137, 181, 7)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='sigmoid',padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=1, activation='sigmoid', padding='same'))
```

Now instead of a single prediction over Australia the image has 42 maps of Australia combined in the pred_fut matrix? [image]

Clearly I'm doing something wrong with how I interpret the input shape and/or output shape. I understand that I get 7 columns because of the 7 predictors, but how do I reshape the files so this doesn't happen? I tried to reshape my data to

```
X_train.shape = (1505,137,181,1)
X_test.shape = (7,137,181,1)
X_fut.shape = (7,137,181,1)
y_train.shape = (215,137,181)
y_test.shape = (1,137,181)
y_fut.shape = (1,137,181)
```

but this then leads to a conflict

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 1505
  y sizes: 215
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
```